Flutter Bloc based ListView pagination not keeping the position
I am working on Bloc based ListView pagination.
but the problem is whenever fetching new data from API and set the data appending to previous state and emit, the ListView is refreshed and the cursor position jump to top of the application.
here is my code below.
screen
class DaumListScreen extends StatelessWidget with DaumLogic {
  const DaumListScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<DaumListBloc, DaumListState>(builder: (context, state) {
      if (state is DaumListLoadedState) {
        List<DaumListValue> daumLists = state.daumList.value;

        return NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>(
          onNotification: (scrollInfo) {
            scrollInfo.metrics.pixels == scrollInfo.metrics.maxScrollExtent
                ? serviceLocator<DaumListBloc>()
                    .add(FetchDaumListNextPageEvent())
                : null;
            return true;
          },
          child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: daumLists.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return DaumListWidget(
                  title: daumLists[index].title,
                  departureDate: daumLists[index].date,
                  thumbnail: daumLists[index].thumbnail,
                  subTitle: daumLists[index].title);
            },
          ),
        );
      }
      // default view
      return const SingleChildScrollView();
    });
  }
}

bloc
class DaumListBloc extends Bloc<DaumListEvent, DaumListState> {
  DaumListBloc({this.daumRepository})
      : assert(daumRepository != null),
        super(InitialDaumListState()) {
    on<FetchDaumListEvent>(((event, emit) async {
      emit(DaumListLoadingState());

      try {
        final DaumList? data = await daumRepository?.fetchDaumList();

        // daum list loaded
        emit(DaumListLoadedState(
            data ?? DaumList(nextToken: "", queryExecutionId: "", value: [])));
      } catch (e) {
        print(e);
        emit(DaumListErrorState(e.toString()));
      }
    }));

    on<FetchDaumListNextPageEvent>(((event, emit) async {
      final currentState = state;
      emit(DaumListLoadingState());

      if (currentState is DaumListLoadedState) {
        final nextToken = currentState.daumList.nextToken;
        final queryExecutionId = currentState.daumList.queryExecutionId;

        try {
          final DaumList data = await daumRepository?.fetchDaumList(
                  nextToken: nextToken, queryExecutionId: queryExecutionId) ??
              DaumList(nextToken: "", queryExecutionId: "", value: []);

          final DaumList concatenatedData = DaumList(
              nextToken: data.nextToken,
              queryExecutionId: data.queryExecutionId,
              value: currentState.daumList.value + data.value);

          // daum list loaded
          emit(DaumListLoadedState(concatenatedData));
        } catch (e) {
          print(e);
          emit(DaumListErrorState(e.toString()));
        }
      } else {
        emit(const DaumListErrorState(
            "pagination failed: previous data does not exist"));
      }
    }));
  }
  final DaumRepository? daumRepository;
}

main
          body: SafeArea(
              child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                    flex: 1,
                    child: MultiBlocProvider(providers: [
                      BlocProvider(
                          create: (context) => serviceLocator<DaumListBloc>()
                            ..add(FetchDaumListEvent()))
                    ], child: const DaumListScreen()))
              ])));
    }));
  }

I have no idea which one is causing the lost of the state of current position.

This happens from BlocBuilder.
As i tested, whenever i change Bloc state the BlocBuilder rebuilding happens.

I changed Bloc Builder to Bloc Listener and it's keeping the position even the state changed.
class DaumListScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const DaumListScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<DaumListScreen> createState() => _DaumListScreenState();
}

class _DaumListScreenState extends State<DaumListScreen> {
  List<DaumListValue> daumLists = [];
  late DaumListBloc _daumListBloc;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _daumListBloc = serviceLocator<DaumListBloc>();
    DaumListState initialState = _daumListBloc.state;
    if (initialState is DaumListLoadedState) {
      setState(() {
        daumLists = initialState.daumList.value;
      });
    }
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocListener<DaumListBloc, DaumListState>(
        listener: (context, state) {
          if (state is DaumListLoadedState) {
            setState(() {
              daumLists = state.daumList.value;
            });
          }
        },
        child: NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>(
          onNotification: (scrollInfo) {
            if (scrollInfo.metrics.pixels ==
                scrollInfo.metrics.maxScrollExtent) {
              _daumListBloc.add(FetchDaumListNextPageEvent());
            }
            return true;
          },
          child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: daumLists.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return DaumListWidget(
                  title: daumLists[index].title,
                  departureDate: daumLists[index].date,
                  thumbnail: daumLists[index].thumbnail,
                  subTitle: daumLists[index].title);
            },
          ),
        ));
  }
}

